# Shell scipt array output

Tags: 16.04, command-line, scripts

I wanted to know how to echo the last value of an array in shell script.
for example I have the following array"

> $i=("1","2","3")

and I wanted to set a condition at the last position, meaning that when it gets on position 3 it stops or it says "hello world".

How can I do that?

EDIT
the shell is shell script as in #!/bin/sh

Comment: `/bin/sh` does not have arrays at all. You want `/bin/bash` (or zsh or ksh)

Comment: Let me explain, I am working with GRASS and I have a problem with a one-dimensional vector of numbers. Now I want to print the length of that vector because my output is looks like this (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,) when it should look like this (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), which means that I don't need the last separator

Comment: Just noticed you crossposted a fuller version of your question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947609/shell-scipt-array-output#947609

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the shell is Bash:

`i=("a" "b" "c"); echo "${i[$((${#i[@]}-1))]}"`

will output `c`. The construction `${#i[@]}` returns the number of elements in array `i`, so that `$((${#i[@]}-1))` is the index of the last element. See [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html) for details; it contains a section named **Arrays**.

`echo "${i[-1]}"`

also echoes `c`, because negative indices are counted from the end of the array.

And array elements inside parentheses are separated by spaces not commas.

Comment: The shell is shell script

Comment: @glennjackman: You are obviously correct and I don't know what I copied and pasted from the terminal. The answer has been edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your array syntax is wrong: you want `i=(1 2 3)`

The last element is

```
$ echo "${i[-1]}"
3
```

However, this smells like [an XY question](http://xyproblem.info/).

Do you actually want to iterate over all-but-the-last elements? Then do this:

```
len=${#i[@]}
for elem in "${i[@]:0:len-1}"; do
    echo "$elem"
done
echo "hello world"
```

Otherwise, what are your actual requirements?